# What are these mystery numbers on the Nescafe disposable coffee sachets?

Tags: instant

I noticed the numbers 1-9 (did not see any with double digits) on these nescafe sachets. Anyone know what they are for?

[image]

Comment: What sort of package did they come from? Were they a pack of 9 and did each number occur once or was it a larger back and did you just find each digit in that package?

Comment: I don't know they are at my work kitchen but I assume they are bought in bulk. I read elsewhere in the web about sachet numbering often referring to the filling machine number used to fill the sachet. But this was for mayo and ketchup sachets